# While importing web3.py getting following error: TypeError: 'ellipsis' object is not iterable

Tags: web3.py

Python version : 3.5.2.
web3 version : 4.9.2.
Ubuntu : 16.04.
Also tried previous version of web3: 4.0.0

Comment: if this fixed your problem please mark my response as answer. thanks

Answer (score 4):

This is a very common error.

You need to upgrade your python version.

Web3 requires at least 3.5.3+

I hope this resolved your problem :D